# Change the CSS Style of an item in VB

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Seems simple but I can't figure it out. I need to change the style of an asp label when an action is performed within the VB code. I already have the style made and in the list of CSS styles I just need to make the labels style equal to specified CSS style I guess. Please let me know how to do this.

It is a school project and the instructions specify that the style must be changed within the VB code. I am using VS 2010.

Thanks in advance, Josh

Comment: I used Zeb Rawnsley's solution as shown below. Label1.CssClass = "MyClass" (I used my style within the parenthesis and without the beginning period.) Thanks Again Zeb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS:

`.MyClass {width:200px; background-color:red; color:blue;}`

HTML:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Code-Behind:

```
Protected Sub SomeMethod()
 ' Some Code
 Label1.CssClass = "MyClass"
 ' Some Code
End Sub
```